# How to create your own special character

Tags: java, parsing

I have my own code and its parser.
The code is in the format

```
valuea~valueb
```

Where `valuea` and `valueb` are `Strings,`
where '~' separates and defines them. 
But there might be a '~' in `valuea` and `valueb`, and this might break my parser.
So how should I handle this?

I was thinking to replace the value '~' in `valuea` and `valueb` with some   other code like `amp1%#$%#` or something like this which is not likely to be used. 
But I still think this is not that good solution.

Do you have any better
or any generalized solution?

Comment: Character `~` an operator?

Comment: you can say that an reserved keyword

Comment: It isn't a keyword at all, it's a special character, and an operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't allow the same character (or sequence of characters) you are going to use for the splitter to also appear in any of the values.

The best two options would be prevent users from putting your reserve character (~) into their value, or pick a new reserve character they are not able to use.

About a generalized solution, there is prior art around escaped and reserved characters in parsers like the one used in bash.

Comment: please give me more about genrelized solution

Comment: any hint what reserved charcter they are not able to use

Comment: The input needs to be "sanitized" i.e. you should be able to validate the two inputs somewhere and prevent them from including any reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to require the value strings to be quoted literals.